# Unhandled promise rejection when trying to get my JWT token from async storage onto the request header using Apollo Client

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo client's setContext and createHttpLink functions to out the JWT token from storage onto the request header but I keep getting an error:
`[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Response not successful: Received status code 500]`

When I create the apollo client object like this my app runs perfectly fine:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://<myIPaddress>:4000/graphql',
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

However, I was following the apollo client docs and I used this chunk of code instead:

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({uri: 'http://<myIPaddress>:4000/graphql'});

const authLink = setContext(async (req, { headers }) => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('AUTH_TOKEN');

  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null
    }
  };
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

But this completely crashes my app whenever I try to run any of my graphql queries or mutations. Any help would be appreciated.

Here are my imports:

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloProvider,
  createHttpLink,
  InMemoryCache
} from '@apollo/client';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
```

Comment: `500` usually means server-side error. The bug might not be in the client.

Comment: That’s what I was thinking too but nothing happens on my server when this error is executed. It just keeps running normally while the client crashes.

Comment: You should look in the network tab of your the browser devtools to find the one returning `500` and see if the error there has more info.